# What is a cloaked message in Facebook

Tags: facebook

A coworker of mine is trying to figure this out and I haven't heard of it before.  What is a "cloaked" message in Facebook?

Comment: Sounds like a scam-application to me.

Comment: in terms of what ? facebook dev ? or a facebook message ?

Comment: This could be some special codename for privacy features which Facebook now employs and your coworker just doesn't understand the right lingo to use. If it's not, refer to the possible reference in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your coworker MAY be talking about a Firefox plugin called [CloakGuard](http://www.cloakguard.com/demo/what.php). It requires all users to have the plugin installed and allows you to obfuscate certain portions of your content on Gmail, Facebook, and a few others using a password.

Not sure how well it works and haven't personally tried it. Here's a [few videos showing it in action](http://www.cloakguard.com/demo/watch.php).

Comment: This seems like the best answer we found.  Not sure I would bother using it, but I'm sure it's for someone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it actually exists: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=facebook+cloaked+message